# Running multiple Stuart-Maxwell tests through looping columns in R

Tags: r, matrix, multiple-columns, crosstab

I have 20 columns each representing a question (profile) and respondents (within subject design)in my survey had to pick one of 5 options (likert scale from A to E).
Now I want to test statistically if the distribution of answers are different in different questions (profiles).In order to to so I have to run Stuart Maxwell test on cross tabs of possible pairwise comparisons of profiles.

so process is really simple if I only had one comparison:
-1 make cross tab (tab1) of responses over Q1 and Q2 for instance
2- Do the SM (stuart.maxwell.mh(tab1))test from "irr" package.
3- extract the p-value

but it is too time consuming to do it like this over 20 questions.
I need a function or loop to do the tests and extract p.values and print them in a matrix for me.
any help please?

```
data <- data.frame(Q1=sample(1:5, 20, replace=T),
               Q2=sample(1:5, 20, replace=T),
               Q3=sample(1:5, 20, replace=T),
               Q4=sample(1:5, 20, replace=T),
               Q5=sample(1:5, 20, replace=T),
               Q6=sample(1:5, 20, replace=T),
               Q7=sample(1:5, 20, replace=T),
               Q8=sample(1:5, 20, replace=T),
               Q9=sample(1:5, 20, replace=T),
               Q10=sample(1:5, 20,replace=T) )  #fake data

choose(n=10, k=2)   # possible pairwise comparisons  n!/k!(n-k)!

library(irr)   # to run Stuart-Maxwell test
crosstab1<-table(data$Q1,data$Q2)
test1<-stuart.maxwell.mh(crosstab1)    
p.value1 <- (test1$p)
```

Comment: Write a function that produces the desired output for a single pairwise comparison; use `combn(simplify = FALSE)` to get a list of all possible pairwise comparisons; use `lapply` to iterate the function over the elements of that list; then simplify the resulting list as desired.

Comment: can you please make a simple example here.

Comment: No, c'mon, man, that's on you. If you post data that's like yours and the code you've used to get started, then we can pick up from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by pairing `combn` with `apply`. From `combn(names(data), m = 2, simplify = FALSE)`, you get a list of all pairwise combinations of columns in `data`. Then you can make a function out of your analytical steps and wrap it in a call to `sapply` to iterate it over the elements of that list. If some of those tests will fail, you can use `try` and then condition the output on the presence of try errors.

```
set.seed(1)
n <- 10
data <- as.data.frame(replicate(n, sample(1:5, 20, replace=T)))
names(data) <- paste0("Q", seq(n))

sapply(combn(names(data), 2, simplify = FALSE), function(i) {

    require(irr)

    xtab <- table(data[,i[1]], data[,i[2]])

    test <- try(stuart.maxwell.mh(xtab))

    ifelse(class(test) == "try-error", NA, test$p)

})
```

Result (error messages omitted):

```
 [1] 0.60653066 0.14569903 0.76409383 0.67869842 0.30610257 0.56851257 0.29978059         NA 0.50186668 0.40946486         NA 0.96507339 0.79040671 0.65190962
[15] 0.04643301 0.31731051 0.19468671 0.13960650 0.32043451 0.18998439 0.05035511 0.26611587 0.31731051 0.10539922 0.42712948 0.79543629 0.43459821 0.12994287
[29] 0.15729921         NA 0.42313825 0.69285237 0.20373938 1.00000000 0.71653131 0.55782540 0.31890656 0.22313016 0.57637784 0.14830902 0.31731051 0.40839235
[43]         NA 0.05488579 0.31731051
```

Comment: it gives an error : "Too many equal marginals, cannot compute" due to non identical consumer responses in all pair comparisons. I think the formula needs to be adjusted for those pairwise comparisons that SM test give error i.e. print "NA" in a matrix of P-values

Comment: It works for me. I've added the steps I used to make data and the result. I wonder if the problem is in differences between the structure of your actual data and the toy data you suggested.

Comment: Yes. I see. Thanks it works in fact. but in real situation i have situation that some of paired comparisons do not yield any test result since the consumers responses are not identical in both profiles. So, if we can adjust the formula in way that allow to print the rest of p-values and put NA for those that are not applicable.

Comment: Not cool to keep moving the goal posts here. Why don't you try formatting the vector returned by `sapply` the way you want it? Hint: get the results of `combn` as an object, then use it to make names for your vector .

Comment: No, sorry, I've got to move on.